# Unique Count in Sliding Window Approach?

Tags: algorithm, bloom-filter

**Edited**

I have the following situation and I would appreciate any ideas how to best solve it:

Let's say I have IPs and each IP have a unique user name.
An IP can log to multiple users.
My system gets from an external process a list of all the users an IP logged in a **day in resolution of minutes** like:

```
00:00 1.1.1.1 "Ben"
00:00 1.1.1.1 "Dan"
00:00 1.1.1.1 "David"
00:00 1.1.1.2 "Ben"
00:01 1.1.1.1 "Dan"
00:01 1.1.1.1 "Bob"
00:01 1.1.1.2 "Dan"
00:01 1.1.1.1 "David"
    ...
    etc
```

What I need to see is if there's an IP that logged to a number of unique users above a certain threshold in 1 hour.

My idea was to use Bloom filter here, since we need to store the info, every IP in every minute will have his own Bloom filter field (from what I saw so far its the best method to conserve space) saving the data of which unique users it logged that minute.
I'm thought of using a single hash function (k=1) so that by doing s sliding window of size 60 mins (an hour) and xor each IP respective Bloom feild, by counting the number of '1' bit I would get the number of unique users got logged to in that hour by that IP.

Now if I have in avarage 1000 IP and lets say each of them have a single unigue user, so 1000 users, the probability of false positive the filter in no more than 0.005 and a single hash, for each IP in a min I would need 199,500bit or 24.35KiB

1440 mins in day * 1000 IPs * 24.35KiB are about 35910MB which is way too much memory... and that's only an average case, there could be 10,000 IP and 20,000 user :/
Is there a better approach for this problem with less space requirements (even in expanse of performance)?

Thank you :)

Comment: If in one minute you cannot check if there are ten different names in the past day, then something seems wrong with your approach.  This does not seem like that intensive an operation, unless you have zillions of logins.  But, with 1,440 minutes in a day and 10 logins per minute, the volume of data is not extraordinary.

Comment: You haven't defined "best", nor have you explained why computing a simple hash function up to ten times a minute is an unacceptable system load.  I would do this with a straightforward table of counters.

Comment: What about the problem makes false positives (a side-effect of the Bloom filter) acceptable?

Comment: “too heavy impact on the system” — since you suggest a bloom filter would help you here, do you mean to say that the “impact” is memory related? What problems are you running into exactly

Comment: You are right, in my attempt to simplify the problem with an example a lot of info got lost in the way, I'm very sorry about that, I edited the post so it reflects the actual problem.
Thank you